# a quick way to access environment $PATH from python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, interpreter

I suppose this is an XY problem and now I know what one of those is I apologise - as I was trying to formulate the question I began to answer it to myself but not completely.

The script is run from the interpreter and is called to write 'n' number of lines from the interpreter history to a text document. I am just beginning to explore python really and this is a fun way making hard copies of my experiments

I'm trying to run a python script from within the python interpreter without an absolute path to the script.

> exec(open('/absolute/path/to/python/scripts/script.py').read())

I know that $PATH is accessed with

> p = os.environ['PATH']

but I'm unsure how I might use this in a way that isn't more long winded than an absolute path.

Thanks enormously in advance.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Also, using `exec` in this manner is weird. Why don't you just add an appropriate `#!` line to the top of the script then simply invoke it like any other program?

Comment: Thanks, now I know what an XY problem is I apologise as I have explained in my edit. The script already has an appropriate shebang but that appears useless when run from the interpreter. I know of no other means of running a script from the interpreter without using exec()